# Update Status doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When clicking "Update Status" on a job page, nothing happens. No network requests are made, and on page load I get an error in the console.

```
68TNyn5gDtY?rel=0:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined(…)
```

[This is the job page if it's relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/128631/hello-again-sky-betting-gaming).

I have AdBlock, but it's disabled for the .stackoverflow.com domain.

Windows 10
Chome Version: 54.0.2840.99

Answer (score 5):

We recently moved some JS around and neglected to notice that this particular component was used in several places. Adding back the code to initialise the component in this particular view fixed it up.

We have an on-going tech debt project to tidy all this up so this should be a less likely occurrence in future.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: No problem :). When I look now, I don't see that box, is that because I've already changed my status in the profile editor?

Comment: Yup, it only appears when your status is considered stale