# Update status button nothing happens when attempting to change job search status

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Related: [Update Status doesn't appear to do anything](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338344/update-status-doesnt-appear-to-do-anything)

I am currently trying to use the update status button and nothing is happening. I have turned off ad blocker and checked firewall.

Is this a bug?

I used the following example test job search then tried clicking update status to no avail.

`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=vba&tl=vba&s=50000&c=GBP`

Using Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report!

It was a classic JQuery mistake on my part. I had the code to show the popup wrapped in an `if (!$('#popup'))` when I meant to say `if (!$('#popup').length)`.

Should be fixed now. Sorry for the delay! (Christmas break and whatnot.)

Comment: thank you for sorting

Answer (score 0):

You might be already known but I just want to share how to update status from settings,

[image]

But in your case probably this could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. It was more the functionality of the button which I was querying in this instance. I decided to start having a play with that part of the site. Wanted to be sure it is not just stupidity on my part (which it still could be...)